# FastAPI return datetime dictionary from endpoint

Tags: python, dictionary, fastapi

I'm building an API on FastAPI 0.103.1, under Python 3.11.2.

I have an endpoint that returns a dictionary with multiple datetime dictionaries. The format is this:

```py
{
    'train_dates': {
        'start_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0),
        'end_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 25, 0, 0)
    },
    'test_dates': {
        'start_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 25, 0, 0),
        'end_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0)
    },
    'forecast_dates': {
        'start_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0, 0),
        'end_date': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 14, 0, 0)
    }
}
```

My endpoint returns it like this:

```py
@router.post("")
async def post_endpoint(payload: dict):
    ...
    return {
        # the whole thing here
    }
```

and this works fine, no errors reported. The web app gets all the values, including the dates, properly formatted:

```json
{
  "train_dates": {
    "start_date": "2018-01-01 00:00:00",
    "end_date": "2018-01-25 00:00:00"
  },
  "test_dates": {
    "start_date": "2018-01-25 00:00:00",
    "end_date": "2018-02-01 00:00:00"
  },
  "forecast_dates": {
    "start_date": "2018-02-01 00:00:00",
    "end_date": "2018-02-14 00:00:00"
  }
}
```

However, if I capture the dictionary in a variable and return that variable:

```py
@router.post("")
async def post_endpoint(payload: dict):
    ...
    model_metadata = {
        # the whole thing here
    }
    return model_metadata
```

this will consistently issue an error on the backend:

```
TypeError: Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

For now, my only option is to do this:

```py
    return json.loads(json.dumps(model_metadata, default=str))
```

which feels like an overkill.

Is there any better way of doing this?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. Using python 3.11.5 and fastapi 0.103.1, it works for me for both cases.

Comment: maybe show FULL error message. Maybe problem is different.

Comment: why you are not using pydantic for handle payload? and show whole error message